# Iterate only one array value as a class PHP

Tags: php

I only want to show one class from an array for  tag. https://prnt.sc/11a9t8p The array show all class instead of one - what loop should I create

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'column_with_repeater') ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'column_with_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <section class="call-to-section">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <h2><?php echo the_sub_field('title'); ?></h2>
                    <h3><?php echo the_sub_field('subtitle'); ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo the_sub_field('description'); ?></p>
                    

                    <?php

                    $icon = array("flaticon-cutlery","flaticon-stethoscope", "flaticon-hotel", "flaticon-police-station");
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'icon' ) ): ?>
                        <ul class="call-to clearfix">
                            <?php while ( has_sub_field( 'icon' ) ) : ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>">
                                        <?php foreach($icon as $icon_list)
                                            echo '<i class="' . $icon_list . '"></i>'
                                        ?>
                                        <?php echo the_sub_field('label'); ?>
                                    </a>                            
                                </li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you only want one value from `$icon`?

Comment: yes and I passed the value on $icon_list

Comment: Well, in that case you don't need a loop to output it. What you need is a way to determine which of the icons needs to be used with which link. I can't tell you how, since there isn't any information in the question regarding that.